# strcmp performance in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, data-structures

```
int myStrCmp (const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const unsigned char *p1 = (const unsigned char *)s1;
    const unsigned char *p2 = (const unsigned char *)s2;

    while (*p1 != '\0') {
       if (*p2 == '\0') return  1;
       if (*p2 > *p1)   return -1;
       if (*p1 > *p2)   return  1;

       p1++;
       p2++;
     }

     if (*p2 != '\0') return -1;

        return 0;
}
```

Does this compare have the notation exactly `O(n)`?. When measured with two strings with s1="abcd" s2="abcd." for the first case and `s1="asdsdcvv"` `s2="asdsdcvv"`. for the second case, does the second case be exactly two times of the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is in O(n) in the average and worst case, where n is the length of the shorter of both given strings. You could also express that as O(min(m,n)) with m and n being the lengths of both strings, respectively.

But no, [O(n) doesn't mean that it needs *exactly* linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). It means that starting from a minimum problem size, all bigger problems will be below some linear function.

If you wanted to know more details, you would need a *very* detailed model of your machine, which seems pretty impossible with modern machines (caching, branch prediction, pipelining, hyper-threading etc.) and Operating Systems (unless you are using a very simple one without multi-tasking).

Comment: yeah I dont think so it is exactly linear thank you. So,I wonder may there be some time (worst worst case)it becomes quadratic?

Comment: yes you are right, at my tests the time is not exact linear. it changes

Comment: @barp: Not "quadratic in terms of the O-notation". In terms of the O-notation it is linear, in the worst and average case. And that's really all you can say without knowing details about the environment. I think you need to learn a bit more about the O-notation. It is an intentionally blurry measure, in order to abstract from machine details that we just don't have in most cases, and tries to still provide something meaningful. You should understand that abstraction before you can really make use of the O-notation.

Comment: Should it not be `min` instead of `max`? The comparison terminates when the shorter string has been examined.